# The send_photo method does not allow sending a picture from the local api to the user

Tags: python, python-requests, localhost, telegram-bot, aiogram

There was such a problem when using the send_photo() method, maybe someone knows a concise solution.

There is a local api that stores the news, it has a field with the url of the image.

This data is obtained without any problems using the get request, but passing the url of the picture to the send_photo method my bot hangs.

I concluded that send_photo searches for pictures by url using the telegram server and therefore cannot find pictures from the local api on the Internet.

How can this be properly corrected?

There was an idea to download pictures from the API to a separate folder and transfer them from there to the send_photo method, and then delete them from the storage, but it seems to me that there is a simpler solution.

In addition, I still do not know how to download images by url in python. This problem can also arise with this approach.

```py
async def get_news(message : types.Message):
  try:
    if message.text.lower() == 'news':
      r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news")
      data = r.json()

      storageURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/"
      photoURL = ""

      i = 0
      while i < len(data):
        photoURL = storageURL + data[i]["preview"]
        await bot.send_photo(
          chat_id=message.chat.id, 
          photo=photoURL, 
          caption=data[i]["title"]
        )
        i += 1
  except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after all by downloading and deleting pictures.
Maybe my way is not beautiful, but it works.
I hope it will be useful to someone.

```py
from aiogram.types.input_file import InputFile
import os

async def get_news(message : types.Message):
  try:
    if message.text.lower() == 'news':
      r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news")
      data = r.json()

      storageURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/"

      i = 0
      while i < len(data): 
        photoURL = storageURL + data[i]["preview"]

        p = requests.get(photoURL)
        newsId = data[i]["id"]

        out = open(f"{newsId}.jpg", "wb")
        out.write(p.content)
        out.close()

        photo = InputFile(f"{newsId}.jpg")

        await bot.send_photo(
          chat_id=message.chat.id, 
          photo=photo,
          caption=data[i]["title"]
        )
 
        os.remove(f"{newsId}.jpg")
        i += 1
        
  except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```